# What are some good Free HttpDebugging Tools

Tags: http, proxy, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I currently use fiddler2 ,paros proxy, Live Http Header and HttpFox.

I would like to know if there are some Free good quality http debugging tools available other than these.

Thanks Again Guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a pretty good (and free) complement to all these tools you are mentioning. I would also recommend [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). It's a lower level PACKET SNIFFER than the ones you've mentioned, but is has a pretty good HTTP decoder.

Comment: Hey Thanks for firebug info, however the issue is I cant use it as a proxy for my application. I want to debug the calls made by my .NET application. Any ideas how firebug can be used in such a scenario?

Comment: @Sumit Ghosh: I see... No. You can't do that with Firebug. I though you were looking to debug HTTP info, not .NET calls. Good luck with your search fellow.

Answer (score 2):

Paros hasnt been updated for many years - 
have a look at the [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project) instead.

Its a free, open source fork of Paros and has been significantly enhanced.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com). It hooks into your ASP.NET MVC/Forms app and provides you with debug info on calls/cache hits and misses/remote calls/etc.

Comment: I am looking for a client side solution. This is more of a server side solution.